# Zoo Triggers Path Paramter adding Root of Site to URL

Tags: structure, transcribe, zoo-triggers

I have EE running with Structure, Transcribe and Zoo Triggers, I have categories in my 'Shop' channel of 'cds', 'digital' and 'merchandise'. Zoo Triggers displays the categories correctly and it displays the entries related to that category correctly but the link it generates is adding the root of my site no matter what I put in the path parameter (my test site is in a sub folder of my main domain). So what I am getting from the following code is:

```
{exp:zoo_triggers:categories channel="shop_item" css_id="subNav" show_counter="no" path="{site_url}index.php/{segment_1}/category"}
     {category_name}
{/exp:zoo_triggers:categories}
```

www.mywebsite.com/http://www.mywebsite.com/clients/client-name/index.php/shop/category/cds

Instead of

http://www.mywebsite.com/clients/client-name/index.php/shop/category/cds

Anyone ever run into this before? Or have a fix for it?

Thanks.
Stephen.

** UPDATE ** 
This is now working as it should, Zoo Triggers released an update.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your system settings and you config.php file to make sure it's not in there.

Comment: Thanks for the response Travis. Where in config.php should I be looking? The weird thing is the path is correct if I don't add a "/" to the path parameter, but as soon as I add a "/" into the path parameter it adds the site root into the url.